# Importing methods with generic type parameters

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I am currently working on adding a new feature to an existing API. Let's say I have a `PerformTediousOperation` method with a generic type parameter:

`void PerformTediousOperation<T>()`

This method is inside a `Operator` class, and can be invoked like this:

`operatorInstance.PerformTediousOperation<T>()`

I want to create a new `Operator` instance and invoke this method, whenever the user marks a type with the `Operable` attribute.

Currently, this is where I am stuck:

```
MethodReference performTediousOperationMethodReference =
    new MethodReference(
        name: "PerformTediousOperation",
        returnType: moduleDefinition.TypeSystem.Void,
        declaringType: operatorTypeReference)
    {
        HasThis = true
    };
```

The emitted IL code (in C#) is simply `PerformTediousOperation();`.

How can I fix this so that the emitted code is instead `PerformTediousOperation<T>()`, where `T` will be determined at runtime?

Please let me know if any more information is desired.

Comment: I'm guessing [`MethodReference.GenericParameters`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/daadf7659817104634be6d2ab30d1ff877fc11f6/Mono.Cecil/MethodReference.cs#L79)?

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, I figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to generate a method that has a generic type parameter using `MonoCecil`:

```
MethodReference performTediousOperationMethodReference =
    new MethodReference(
        name: "PerformTediousOperation",
        returnType: moduleDefinition.TypeSystem.Void,
        declaringType: operatorTypeReference)
    {
        HasThis = true
    };

var genericParameter = new GenericParameter("T", performTediousOperationMethodReference);
performTediousOperationMethodReference.GenericParameters.Add(genericParameter);

GenericInstanceMethod performTediousOperationInstanceMethod = 
    new GenericInstanceMethod(performTediousOperationMethodReference) 
        {
            GenericArguments = { moduleDefinition.ImportReference(typeof(int)) }
        };
```

This generates `PerformTediousOperation<int>()`.

You may pass any other `TypeReference` instance to the `GenericArguments` field, and the output will differ accordingly. E.g. if you pass in `moduleDefinition.ImportReference(typeof(string))` instead, the output will be `PerformTediousOperation<string>()`.

Comment: What is `runTimeDeterminedType`? It doesn't appear in your question or elsewhere in your answer, which makes this somewhat useless for other people who have the same question

Comment: In my case, `runTimeDeterminedType` refers to the type that is marked with the `Operable` attribute. E.g. if I have a `DummyClass` that is marked as `Operable`, the generated IL code would be `PerformTediousOperation<DummyClass>()`.

Comment: I guess `runTimeDeterminedType` is a bad name;  but basically the idea is that whatever `TypeReference` you pass into the `GenericArguments` field will show up as the type specified inside `<>`.

Comment: Could you perhaps post some more self-contained code, which could be of use to others with the same problem?

Comment: @canton7 Thanks for your feedback. I have updated the answer as requested. Is it clearer now?